# Go get all dependencies returns unrecognized import path for Terratest

Tags: go, terratest

**Configuration**

- go1.15.2 darwin/amd64
- macOS Catalina v10.15.7

`.zshrc` file

```sh
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export GOROOT=/usr/local/opt/go/libexec
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm new to Go, and trying to use Terratest to write a test for a Packer build.

When trying to run `go test my_test.go` I keep getting errors saying I need to install missing packages.

> ../../../../../go/src/github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/aws/sqs.go:10:2: cannot find package "github.com/google/uuid" in any of:
> /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/github.com/google/uuid (from $GOROOT)
> /Users/username/go/src/github.com/google/uuid (from $GOPATH).
> FAIL    command-line-arguments [setup failed]
> FAIL

Googling around I found that running `go get -u ./...` from the directory where my test file is should install these packages

**Problem**

When I run `go get -u ./...` I get the following error:

> package _/Users/username/github.com/my-org/my-repo/packer/tests: unrecognized import path "_/Users/username/github.com/my-org/my-repo/packer/tests": import path does not begin with hostname

For additional context, this is the directory structure I'm using:

```
~ 
    github.com/my-org/my-repo/
        packer/
            tests/
                my_test.go
```

And here is the test file, which I've created using [this terratest example](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/blob/master/test/packer_basic_example_test.go) as a reference:

```golang
package test

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/packer"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    terratest_aws "github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/aws"
)

func TestMyAmiBuild( t *testing.T) {

    awsRegion := "us-east-1"

    packerOptions := &packer.Options{
        // Path to the Packer template under test
        Template: "../template/template.json",

        // Variables to pass to Packer build
        Vars: map[string]string{
            "ami_name": "my-ami"
        },

        // Only build the AWS AMI
        Only: "amazon-ebs",
    }

    // Build the Packer template
    amiID := packer.BuildArtifact(t, packerOptions)

    // Clean up the AMI after we're done
    defer terratest_aws.DeleteAmiAndAllSnapshots(t, awsRegion, amiID)

    // Check if AMI is private
    amiIsPublic := terratest_aws.GetAmiPubliclyAccessible(t, awsRegion, amiID)
    assert.False(t, amiIsPublic)
}
```

Comment: Hello, you selected good tools, you are almost there :-) The main problem is that you are using the old way of Go, before modules. 1. Unexport all the env vars, they are just adding confusion and errors; 2. no need any more to put your code under GOPATH, put it where you want; 3 read about and use go mod init. For go module intro, see "Quick start" of https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules